# Extract task graph from pintool

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, scheduled-tasks, intel-pin

Is there a way to extract task graph of a multi thread application by [pintool](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool)?
suppose to have a system with n cores, I want to know the code that running on any core. and also I would like to know the dependency between this parts of code(task)?

Comment: If you mean an existing pintool, I'm afraid the answer is "not in general" - pin can't track tasks in a thread and dependencies are also somewhat higher level

Comment: If you just want to know, for any moment in time, which code was executed in each core and memory locations that were accessed by multiple threads, that is more feasible.

Comment: yse I want to know, for any moment in time, which code was executed in each core...

Comment: Okay, but you realize that this knowledge isn't by itself enough to create a task graph? Without additional knowledge, you won't be able to tell which thread interactions happened and what dependencies exist between the various parts of the code